# Add php variable to select options value

Tags: php, sql

On my webshop search page, i have a select dropdown. With that, i can sort the result by price, name...

The word for i searched, is in the $_GET array. kereses.php?k=test, i created a var of this, like:

```
$k = mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs, $_GET['k']);
```

How can i add this $k variable to the select options?

```
echo '<form method="get" name="listing_items">';
                            echo '<select class="form-control" onchange="listing_items.submit()" name="order">';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='new'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="new">Legújabb termékek</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='nev_asc'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="nev_asc">Név, A – Z</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='nev_desc'?' selected="selected"':'').'value="nev_desc">Név, Z - A</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='price_asc'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="price_asc">Ár szerint növekvő</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='price_desc'?' selected="selected"':'').'value="price_desc">Ár szerint csökkenő</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='cikk_asc'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="cikk_asc">Cikkszám szerint növekvő</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='cikk_desc'?' selected="selected"':'').'value="cikk_desc">Cikkszám szerint csökkenő</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='suly_asc'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="suly_asc">Súly szerint növekvő</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='suly_desc'?' selected="selected"':'').'value="suly_desc">Súly szerint csökkenő</option>';
                            echo '</select>';
                            echo '</form>';
```

The $order variable stores the text, that i put in the sql in the order by.

```
if($order == 'suly_asc'){$orderby = "ORDER BY termek_suly ASC";}
                    if($order == 'suly_desc'){$orderby = "ORDER BY termek_suly DESC";}
                    if($order == 'cikk_asc'){$orderby = "ORDER BY termek_cikkszam ASC";}
                    if($order == 'cikk_desc'){$orderby = "ORDER BY termek_cikkszam DESC";}
                    if($order == 'price_asc'){$orderby = "ORDER BY (CASE termek_akcio WHEN 1 THEN termek_akcios_ar WHEN 0 THEN termek_normal_ar ELSE NULL END ) ASC";}
                    if($order == 'price_desc'){$orderby = "ORDER BY (CASE termek_akcio WHEN 1 THEN termek_akcios_ar WHEN 0 THEN termek_normal_ar ELSE NULL END ) DESC";}
                    if($order == 'nev_asc'){$orderby = "ORDER BY termek_nev ASC";}
                    if($order == 'nev_desc'){$orderby = "ORDER BY termek_nev DESC";}
                    elseif($order == 'new'){$orderby = "ORDER BY termek_id DESC";}
```

**UPDATE:**

When the kereses.php page shows up, the url and the $_GET looks like: kereses.php?k=test

If i choose an option, to sort the result, i want the url and GET looked like:
kereses.php?k=test&sort_by=price_asc

**Update 2, working code:**

```
$order = isset($_GET["order"]) ? $_GET["order"]:'new';
                    if(isset($_GET['k']))
                    {
                        $k = mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs, $_GET['k']);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $k = "";
                    }
                    echo '<div class="pull-left"><p>A keresett kifejezés: <b>'.$k.'</b></p></div>';
                    echo '<div class="pull-right">';
                            echo '<form method="get" name="listing_items">';
                            echo '<input type="hidden" name="k" value="'.html($_GET['k']).'">';
                            echo '<select class="form-control" onchange="listing_items.submit()" name="order">';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='new'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="new">Legújabb termékek</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='nev_asc'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="nev_asc">Név, A – Z</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='nev_desc'?' selected="selected"':'').'value="nev_desc">Név, Z - A</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='price_asc'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="price_asc">Ár szerint növekvő</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='price_desc'?' selected="selected"':'').'value="price_desc">Ár szerint csökkenő</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='cikk_asc'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="cikk_asc">Cikkszám szerint növekvő</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='cikk_desc'?' selected="selected"':'').'value="cikk_desc">Cikkszám szerint csökkenő</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='suly_asc'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="suly_asc">Súly szerint növekvő</option>';
                                    echo '<option '. ($order=='suly_desc'?' selected="selected"':'').'value="suly_desc">Súly szerint csökkenő</option>';
                            echo '</select>';
                            echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Do you wan to display `$k` as an option for the user to choose from?

Comment: No, i want to attach the $k var to the selectable options. Now if i choose an option, de $k var gets out of the GET. On a simple search without option choosen, the url looks like: kereses.php?k=test, and i want, if i choose a option to sort the result is, kereses.php?k=test&order=price_asc.

Comment: So, lets say $k ="Hello". So will ur option be `Legújabb termékek Hello`? etc.

Comment: No. In the GET, there are also the k=test.  If i coose an option, i want to subjoin the selected options value to the GET.

Comment: I still dont get it, can u update the question with what ur expected result should be. Add ur before url, after clicking url etc.

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Give my answer a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the orginal GET somewhere. Here is a an example:

```
echo '<form method="get" name="listing_items">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="k" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['k']);?>">';
    echo '<select class="form-control" onchange="listing_items.submit()" name="order">';
        echo '<option '. ($order=='new'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="new">Legújabb termékek</option>';
        echo '<option '. ($order=='nev_asc'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="nev_asc">Név, A – Z</option>';
        echo '<option '. ($order=='nev_desc'?' selected="selected"':'').'value="nev_desc">Név, Z - A</option>';
        echo '<option '. ($order=='price_asc'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="price_asc">Ár szerint növekvő</option>';
        echo '<option '. ($order=='price_desc'?' selected="selected"':'').'value="price_desc">Ár szerint csökkenő</option>';
        echo '<option '. ($order=='cikk_asc'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="cikk_asc">Cikkszám szerint növekvő</option>';
        echo '<option '. ($order=='cikk_desc'?' selected="selected"':'').'value="cikk_desc">Cikkszám szerint csökkenő</option>';
        echo '<option '. ($order=='suly_asc'?' selected="selected"':'').' value="suly_asc">Súly szerint növekvő</option>';
        echo '<option '. ($order=='suly_desc'?' selected="selected"':'').'value="suly_desc">Súly szerint csökkenő</option>';
    echo '</select>';
echo '</form>';
```

I'm storing the value of `$_GET['k']` back in the GET form as a hidden attribute.

Comment: Okay, not it works, but i dont understand, that how did the GET stores this data after i selected any options. But it works! :)